# Adding more than one string to a controller find condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, controller, conditional-statements

I have the following code in one of my Rails (3.1) controllers:

```
@count = Call.where(:destination => current_user.destination_id).count

@count_day = Call.where('created_at > ?', 1.days.ago).count
@count_month = Call.where('created_at > ?', 30.days.ago).count
```

They are all working as expected, but I am trying to somehow merge two of them together so it shows the count of calls created in the last 1 day, but only for calls with a destination that matches the current users destination_id value.

I have tried to add :condition but with no joy:

```
@count_day = Call.where(:destination => current_user.destination_id, :condition ['created_at > ?', 1.days.ago]).count
```

Is it possible to add more than one condition in this way? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where creates a scope and scopes can be chained, so you can do

```
Call.where(:destination =>current_user.id).where("created_at > ?", 1.day.ago).count
```

Comment: For some reason that outputs `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x132da1d48>` rather than the call count.

Comment: If you want the count, stick `.count` on the end - I was just illustrating that `where` could be chained

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@count_day = Call.where("destination = :destination AND created_at > :date", { :destination => current_user.destination_id, :date => 1.days.ago}).count
```

Comment: If I use your code `@count_day = Call.where(:conditions=>['destination=(?) AND created_at>(?)',current_user.destination_id, 1.days.ago]).count` then I get the following error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: calls.conditions: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "calls"  WHERE "calls"."conditions" IN ('destination=(?) AND created_at>(?)', '01772232427', '2012-01-13 12:57:40.453694')`