# Rails filtering records from the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following code in my Calls controller:

```
@calls = Call.where(:destination => ("1234"),
                    :destination => ("5678"),
                    :destination => ("91011"))
```

Although the above code works, it's only listing records with a destination of 91011. I would somehow like to show all records of which the destination field matches any of the numbers.

I'm unsure as to whether or not I should be adding a .where statement for each filter or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is very similar [to another question I asked a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862065/adding-more-than-one-string-to-a-controller-find-condition). However, that was to further filter a find condition rather than widen the scope.

Comment: Try using `@calls = Call.find(:destination => {:in => ["1234", "5678", "91011"]})`. I'm not 100% sure this works, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@calls = Call.where(:destination => ["1234", "5678", "91011"])
```

Also, if you're on ruby 1.9, you can use the new hash syntax:

```
@calls = Call.where(destination: ["1234", "5678", "91011"])
```

#### Update:

For a limit, there's a method

```
@calls = Call.where(destination: ["1234", "5678", "91011"]).limit(10)
```

I strongly suggest you read about [ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), it's awesome!

Comment: Worked a charm thanks! Is it also possible to add in a :limit => 10 filter? @calls = Call.where(:destination => ["1234", "5678", "91011"], :limit => 10) doesn't seem to work.